# Determining why a php script is slow to execute

Tags: php, time

I have a php script which runs a bash script to terminate a process and start a new instance of the process. Unfortunately on trying to run it, it takes extremely long to run. How can I determine why? It's an apache2 server on a Debian 7 dedicated server.

The php script:

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST');  
$start = microtime(TRUE);  
if (isset($_GET['resetnow'])) {
   $myreset = $_GET['resetnow'];
   if ($myreset == "now") {
         $cmd=getcwd()."/resetut.sh  2>&1";
         exec($cmd, $output, $return_var);
         $outputstr=implode(",", $output);
         $finish = microtime(TRUE);  
         $totaltime = $finish - $start;      
         $timetaken = " This script took ".$totaltime." seconds to run"; 
         print $cmd." ".$outputstr.$timetaken;
   } else {
         print "Didnt receive correct parameters";
   }
} else {
  print "Undefined";
}
?>
```

The shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd pathto/utorrent
killall utserver
./utstart start
a=$(pgrep utserver)
echo Utorrent restarted as new process $a
```

Unfortunately the output looks like this:

```
/pathto/resetut.sh 2>&1 Starting utorrent server,
Utorrent restarted as new process 25044 25381 
This script took 275.10148310661 seconds to run
```

which is way too long. If the shell script is executed from command line, it takes less than a second to complete.

Comment: Do you get about the same run time running the php script from the command line vs initiating from the browser?

Comment: It's called `profiling` and there are tools for doing that. Google for more

Comment: @Samsquanch Yes I do

Comment: This issue may have many reasons, one of them is a hardware problems, you have to ask about the list of reasons and work on it to neglect each of its items then the remaining reason should be the cause root of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few tools at your disposal being on Linux. You can view all the process running using either the "ps" or "top" command(s). These will show you a list of all running processes. My guess is that other programs are taking advantage of the CPU, and you may want to kill them.

If that's not the case, you could use the "time" command to do some time tests. With both PHP and Bash being shell scripts, they are going to run a little slower in comparison to a C++ program because both PHP and Bash have to be interpreted every single time you run them.